# Cypress filter log by event type

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

Here's my issue: I have a big form where I want to perform an e2e test. This form is populating URL query parameters as the user changes a value in its fields.

When I use Cypress to check it, it produces a huge amount of logs (e.g. (new URL) see below) every time something is typed in the form, making tests hard to read.

```js
http://localhost:3000/demande-immersion?email=&firstName=Archib&lastName=&phone=&financiaryHelp=&emergencyContact=&emergencyContactPhone=&birthdate=&agencyDepartment=86&siret=&businessName=&businessAdvantages=&etFirstName=&etLastName=&etJob=&etPhone=&etEmail=&erFirstName=&erLastName=&erPhone=&erEmail=&immersionAddress=&agencyId=1411b4b7-a7a8-4d69-92ac-1eca1ac75c50&immersionActivities=&immersionSkills=&sanitaryPreventionDescription=&workConditions=&dateStart=2023-04-27&dateEnd=2023-04-28&schedule=%7B%22totalHours%22%3A14%2C%22workedDays%22%3A2%2C%22isSimple%22%3Atrue%2C%22selectedIndex%22%3A0%2C%22complexSchedule%22%3A%5B%7B%22date%22%3A%222023-04-27T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%22%2C%22timePeriods%22%3A%5B%7B%22start%22%3A%2208%3A00%22%2C%22end%22%3A%2212%3A00%22%7D%2C%7B%22start%22%3A%2213%3A00%22%2C%22end%22%3A%2216%3A00%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22date%22%3A%222023-04-28T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%22%2C%22timePeriods%22%3A%5B%7B%22start%22%3A%2208%3A00%22%2C%22end%22%3A%2212%3A00%22%7D%2C%7B%22start%22%3A%2213%3A00%22%2C%22end%22%3A%2216%3A00%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D
```

Is there a way to filter the events that Cypress is logging in to the app (using `cypress open`)?

Answer (score 5):

You can remove fetch and xhr using

```js
cy.intercept({ resourceType: /xhr|fetch/ }, { log: false })
```

See [proxy-logging](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/039ebad2205ab4ebc6070c2a726c6197f84a0b11/packages/driver/cypress/e2e/cypress/proxy-logging.cy.ts#L420)

```js
it('can disable fetch logs', () => {
  const logs: any[] = []

  cy.intercept({ resourceType: 'fetch' }, { log: false }).as('fetch')
    .then(() => {
      cy.on('log:added', (log) => {
        if (log.name !== 'request') return
          logs.push(log)
      })

      return fetch(`/foo?${Date.now()}`)
    })
    .wait('@fetch')
    .then(() => {
      expect(logs).to.have.length(0)
    })
  })
})
```

This removes network traffic from the log, if you want to remove commands or queries use `{log: false}` case-by-case or overwrite the command globally.

---

You can also truncate long entries as per this answer [Hide URL in Cypress Info Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75024546/16695029)

```js
Cypress.on('log:changed', (log, interactive) => {
  const logs = window.top.document.querySelectorAll('.command-message-text')
  const last = [...logs][logs.length - 1]
  if (last.innerText.length > 20) {
    last.innerText = last.innerText.slice(0, 20) + '...'
  }
})
```

Comment: I ended up using :
`Cypress.on("log:added", () => {
  const logs = window.top.document.querySelectorAll(".command-name-new-url");
  logs.forEach((log) => log.classList.add("hidden"));
});`